# Process Remote url/ip adress of user in Logback Logging Pattern

Tags: java, logging, logback, converters

I have the following logback pattern:

```
<pattern>%clr(%-6id) - %clr(%d{dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss}) - %clr(%-40.40logger{39}) - %m -%clr(%5p) - [%thread] - %clr(:) %n%wEx</pattern>>
```

I need to process the ip adress of user with logback like this `24.33.87.53`, during the compilation of my program I can see:

```
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 6 ms - INFO - [RMI TCP Connection(1)-198.163.6.156] : Completed initialization in 6 ms
```

In my pattern `[%thread]` is responsible for RMI TCP Connection, but when I'm calling logger like this `logger.info("User connected")` I'm getting `http-nio-8000-exec-1` instead

Trying different VPN connections I realised that this RMI TCP Connection is probably the thing I need.
Now I'm trying to write custom ProcessIpConverter like this

```
public class ProcessIpConverter extends ClassicConverter {
    
    @Override
    public String convert(final ILoggingEvent event) {
        
        return smth;
    }
}
```

and connect it to my pattern with the conversionRule

```
<conversionRule conversionWord="remoteIp"
                    converterClass="com.myPath.ProcessIpConverter" />
```

I tried different ways to get this IP, but didn't find the correct way. So, I'm asking for help, how should I call my DispatcherServlet and how to get this RMI TCP Connection from it. How should I write ProcessIpConverter?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my question here https://www.programmersought.com/article/36461409856/.
Actually should have written ProcessIpConverter like this:

```
public class ProcessIpConverter extends ClassicConverter {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogIpConfig .class);
 
    @Override
    public String convert(ILoggingEvent event) {
        try {
            return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Logger.error("Get log Ip exception", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```